# Сервер не отвечает на запросы

Tags: c++, winsock

Сервер отвечает ок велком и висит ничего не принимая. Через какое-то время он прощаеся и говорит таймаут.

```
WSADATA wsa_data;
WSAStartup(0x101, &wsa_data);
SOCKET s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
SOCKADDR_IN sa;
sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
sa.sin_port = htons(IMAPTLS);
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  ((BYTE *)&sa.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr)[i] = gethostbyname(IMAP)->h_addr_list[0][i];
for(int connect_res = connect(s, (SOCKADDR *)&sa, sizeof(sa));connect_res;connect_res = connect(s, (SOCKADDR *)&sa,   sizeof(sa)))
  Sleep(200); 
while(1){
  const int size=26000;
  char* req=new char[256];
  char buf[size];

  cout << "Введите текст запроса:\n";

  cin.getline(req,256);
  send (s, req, strlen(req), 0);
  recv(s, buf, size, 0); 

  cout << "@:";

  for(int i=0; buf[i] && i<size;i++)
    cout << buf[i];
  cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Вполне возможно что сервер так и должен работать.

Comment: А еще у вас в цикле new без delete и будет утечка памяти, но к поведению сервера это наверняка не относится...

Comment: Добавил delete. Как сервер должен работать я и сам не знаю, так как не знаю какой порядок команд должен идти. попробовал по логике send-recv но что-то не прокатывает

Comment: Ну если вы не уверены, что сервер должен делать что-то еще, почему вы считаете что что-то не так? Это может быть нормальная работа сервера.

Comment: и send, и recv не гарантируют, что прочитают/запишут все байты. Они возвращают кол-во записанных/прочитанных байт. И если в локальной сети и при размере до 1000 байт обычно все ещё как то читается/пишется, то в обычном интернете уже обычно нет.
Дальше - больше. Вы отправляете данные на сервере, но откуда серверу знать, сколько именно нужно читать. А так как код сервера не понятен, то и скорее всего в этом и проблема.

Comment: Оказывается чтобы сервер понял что команда закончена, ему нужно послать последовательность "\r\n", чего я, собственно, не делал. На неправильную команду сервер тут же стал отвечать BAD. Проблема решена, спасибо всем кто отписался.